# Writing config.cfg for htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, latex2html, cfg

I wish to write my own `config.cfg` file (used by `htlatex` to convert `.tex` to `html`) that uses my custom defined header/footer, frames and background.

Comment: refer the tutorial by Michal https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial

Comment: what do you need to help with?

Comment: A tutorial is needed to enable latex users, with a basic understanding of php and html, to write their own config.cfg with a specific header/footer and style(including frame).